# How can I do width = 100% - 100px in CSS?

Tags: html, css

In CSS, how can I do something like this:

```
width: 100% - 100px;
```

I guess this is fairly simple but it is a bit hard to find examples showing that.

Comment: The linked question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093943/is-it-possible-to-make-a-div-50px-less-than-100-in-css?newsletter=1&nlcode=78829%7c765d gives an interesting, but not fully backward compatible answer, maybe you would like to take a look on that too.

Comment: For anyone who crosses this question Chad answered that modern browsers supports `width: calc(100% - 100px);` it's a few answers down and I hope the asker will update his question :) :)

Answer (score 364, accepted):

Modern browsers now support the:

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

To see the list of supported browser versions checkout: [Can I use calc() as CSS unit value?](http://caniuse.com/calc)

There is a jQuery fallback: [css width: calc(100% -100px); alternative using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117216/css-width-calc100-100px-alternative-using-jquery?rq=1)

Comment: I found when I was using `calc(100% - 6px)` for example it was displaying as `calc(94%)`, I had to escape it as follows and now it works `width: calc(~"100% - 6px");`

Comment: Be aware, you must have whitespace around the `-` (or `+`) character.  This works: `calc(100% - 100px);`  And this doesn't: `calc(100%-100px);`

Comment: I'm a little surprised there's no option to automatically subtract 2x the padding of the element, which would usually be a pretty common usecase.  E.g., I end up having to do `padding: 0.25em; width: calc(100% - 2 * 0.25em - 2em);`, and would have to change the `0.25em` in two places now if it has to be amended.

Comment: So many thanks, would also like to note that it works for addition: (100% + 100px)

Answer (score 100):

Could you nest a div with `margin-left: 50px;` and `margin-right: 50px;` inside a `<div>` with `width: 100%;`?

Comment: width: calc(100% - 100px);
this is correct answer instead.

Answer (score 21):

You can try this...

```html
<!--First Solution-->
width: calc(100% - 100px);
<!--Second Solution-->
width: calc(100vh - 100px);
```

vw: viewport width

vh: viewport height

Comment: First solution is correct, the container might not be the window and therefore 100vh might not equal 100%

Comment: I found when I was using `calc(100% - 6px)` for example it was displaying as `calc(94%)`, I had to escape it as follows and now it works `width: calc(~"100% - 6px");`

Answer (score 7):

It started to work for me only when I checked all the spaces. 
So, it didn't work like this: `width: calc(100%- 20px)` or `calc(100%-20px)` and perfectly worked with `width: calc(100% - 20px)`.

Answer (score 5):

my code, and it works for IE6:

```
<style>
#container {margin:0 auto; width:100%;}
#header { height:100px; background:#9c6; margin-bottom:5px;}
#mainContent { height:500px; margin-bottom:5px;}
#sidebar { float:left; width:100px; height:500px; background:#cf9;}
#content { margin-left:100px; height:500px; background:#ffa;}

</style>

<div id="container">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="mainContent">
    <div id="sidebar">left</div>
    <div id="content">right 100% - 100px</div>
  <span style="display:none"></span></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What is that Javascript for?

Answer (score 4):

You need to have a container for your content div that you wish to be 100% - 100px

```
#container {
   width: 100%
}
#content {
   margin-right:100px;
   width:100%;
}

<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
      Your content here
  </div>
</div>
```

You might need to add a clearing div just before the last `</div>` if your content div is overflowing.

```
<div style="clear:both; height:1px; line-height:0">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: This will not work.  The content width will be 100%: http://jsfiddle.net/cuezK/1/

Answer (score 2):

Setting the body margins to 0, the width of the outer container to 100%, and using an inner container with 50px left/right margins seems to work.

```
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.full-width
{
    width: 100%;
}

.innerContainer
{
    margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px;
}
</style>

<body>
  <div class="full-width" style="background-color: #ff0000;">
    <div class="innerContainer" style="background-color: #00ff00;">
      content here
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Working with bootstrap panels, I was seeking how to place "delete" link in header panel, which would not be obscured by long neighbour element. And here is the solution:

html:

```
<div class="with-right-link">
    <a class="left-link" href="#">Long link header Long link header</a>
    <a class="right-link" href="#">Delete</a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.with-right-link { position: relative; width: 275px; }
a.left-link { display: inline-block; margin-right: 100px; }
a.right-link { position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; }
```

Of course you can modify "top" and "right" values, according to your indentations. [Source](https://jsfiddle.net/w0mwuye7/)

Answer (score 1):

Could you do:

```
margin-right: 50px;
margin-left: 50px;
```

**Edit:**  My solution is wrong.  The solution posted by Aric TenEyck suggesting using a div with width 100% and then nesting another div using the margins seems more correct.

Comment: If you do this, won't you end up with the total width being 100% + 100px?

Comment: :o(  I'm sorry.  Should I delete my post or should I leave it and let the down votes push it down?

Comment: down votes are usually meant to encourage you to clean up your post so you can regain rep points lost by the negative votes. If you know your solution to be wrong you can delete if with or without down votes or update it to make it right.

Comment: @AdamCrume - Nope.  That would only be the case if you also specified `width:100%`.  A div will automatically fill the container unless you override that, eg, by explicitly specifying `width`, or by using `float` or absolute positioning.  Adding a margin to a div will just cause it to fill its container, less the amount specified by the margin.

Comment: @aleemb - In this case the downvotes are by users who don't understand css as this answer is perfectly correct.

Comment: @fmsf - If this solution isn't working, it's because you are doing something more to your div.  Do you also have `width: 100%` on this div?  Are you using `float`?

Comment: @Tina - Your answer is 100% correct, and a more elegant solution than Aric's because it doesn't require modifying the markup.  There already is a parent element, so adding a separate div is redundant.  A div automatically expands to fill its container so specifying `width:100%` is unnecessary and actually causes bad side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Padding on the outer div will get the desired effect.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    #outer{
        padding: 0 50px;
        border:1px solid black; /*for visualization*/
    }

    #inner{
        border:1px solid red; /*for visualization*/
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        100px smaller than outer
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 techniques which can come in handy for this common scenario. Each have their drawbacks but can both be useful at times.

**box-sizing: border-box** includes padding and border width in the width of an item.
For example, if you set the width of a div with 20px 20px padding and 1px border to 100px, the actual width would be 142px but with border-box, both padding and margin are inside the 100px.

```
.bb{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;     
    width: 100%;
    height:200px;
    padding: 50px;
}
```

Here's an excellent article on it: http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/ and here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/L3Rvw/

And then there's **position: absolute**

```
.padded{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    right: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    bottom: 50px;
    background-color: #aefebc;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mw9CT/1/

Neither are perfect of course, box-sizing doesn't exactly fit the question as the element is actually 100% width, rather than 100% - 100px (however a child div would be). And absolute positioning definitely can't be used in every situation, but is usually okay as long as the parent height is set.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <br>
    <div style="margin: 0px 50px 0px 50px; border: 1px solid blue;">
        <br>
    </div>
    <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using standards mode? This solution depends on it I think.

If you're trying to make 2 columns you could do something like this:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="left">
        sidebar
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        lorem ispsum etc... 
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use CSS to style it:

```
div#outer
{
    width:100%;
    height: 500px;
}

div#left
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    background: green;
}

div#main
{
   width: auto;
   margin-left: 100px; /* same as div#left width */
   height: 100%;
   background:red;
}
```

If you don't want 2 columns you can probably remove `<div id="left">`

Answer (score 0):

You can look into using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/), which is a JavaScript file that pre-processes your CSS so you can include logic and variables into your CSS. So for your example, in LESS you would write `width: 100% - 100px;` to achieve exactly what you wanted :)

Answer (score -1):

**CSS can not be used to animation, or any style modification on events.**

The only way is to use a javascript function, which will return the width of a given element, then, subtract 100px to it, and set the new width size.

Assuming you are using jQuery, you could do something like that:

```
oldWidth = $('#yourElem').width();
$('#yourElem').width(oldWidth-100);
```

And with native javascript:

```
oldWidth = document.getElementById('yourElem').clientWidth;
document.getElementById('yourElem').style.width = oldWidth-100+'px';
```

We assume that you have a css style set with 100%;

Answer (score -2):

This works:

```
margin-right:100px;
width:auto;
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation to your answer?

Comment: I've tried: calc(100%-100px) and the results aren't consistent accross all platforms/browsers, then I tried to really simplify and used margin-right:100px;
width:auto; and it worked...

Comment: calc is CSS3 component and this css will work on those browsers which supports CSS3.

Answer (score -3):

You can't.

You can, however, use margins to effect the same result.