# css width: calc(100% -100px); alternative using jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to use `width: calc(100% -100px);` which does the job perfectly for what I need it for, the only problem is its compatibility. At the moment it only works in the latest browsers and not at all in Safari.

Could I make an alternative using jQuery? ie. get the 100% width of an object -100px and then dynamically set the result as the CSS width (so it would be responsive)

Comment: use in this way with jquery $('#dataElement').css({'width':'calc(100% -100px)'});

Answer (score 117, accepted):

If you have a browser that doesn't support the `calc` expression, it's not hard to mimic with jQuery:

```
$('#yourEl').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=100px');
```

It's much easier to let jQuery handle the relative calculation than doing it yourself.

Comment: [http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/](http://tobiasahlin.com/blog/quick-guide-chaining-in-jquery/)

Comment: @odiszapc add `$(window).resize(function() { /* put the jquery calc code here */ });` so it will auto calculate the width during a window  resize.

Comment: I know it. See my answer below

Comment: This approach has a small problem. When I change the width of page, the width of `#yourEl` does not change, it is constant.

Comment: Just incase other people are anal about formatting, there cannot be a space between '=' and the value. So `-= 100px` will not work, it must be `-=100px`.

Answer (score 27):

I think this may be another way

```
    var width=  $('#elm').width();

    $('#element').css({ 'width': 'calc(100% - ' + width+ 'px)' });
```

Answer (score 18):

100%-100px is the same

```
div.thediv {
  width: auto;
  margin-right:100px;
}
```

With jQuery:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('.thediv').each(function(){
    $(this).css('width', $(this).parent().width()-100);
  })
});
```

Similar way is to use [jQuery resize plugin](https://github.com/alessandro-sena/jQuery-Resize-Plugin)

Comment: with the top example, would that work if the item is `position:absolute; top:0; left:0; `

Comment: just been playing arround with it, in your js it throughts up an error on line 2 the $(window) line `<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).resize(){
  $('#supersized').each(function(){
    $(this).css('width', $(this).parent().width()-100);
  })
}
        </script>`

Comment: Would you css example work if it was `width:90%; margin-right:-100px;`

Answer (score 1):

Try  jQuery `animate()` method, ex.

```
$("#divid").animate({'width':perc+'%'});
```

Comment: I'm actually trying to use animate with the calc function described above, but having trouble:`$('#button-sidebar').animate({width: calc(50% + 20px)},400);`

Comment: I don't think that you can use jQuery to animate calc Css variables. You could animate both `'width', '100%'` and `'width', '-=100px'` in the same action and it will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Its not that hard to replicate in javascript :-) , though it will only work for width and height the best but you can expand it as per your expectations :-)

```
function calcShim(element,property,expression){
    var calculated = 0;
    var freed_expression = expression.replace(/ /gi,'').replace("(","").replace(")","");
    // Remove all the ( ) and spaces 
    // Now find the parts 
    var parts = freed_expression.split(/[\*+-\/]/gi);

    var units = {
        'px':function(quantity){
            var part = 0;
            part = parseFloat(quantity,10);
            return part;
        },
        '%':function(quantity){
            var part = 0,
            parentQuantity = parseFloat(element.parent().css(property));
            part = parentQuantity * ((parseFloat(quantity,10))/100);
            return part;
        } // you can always add more units here.
    }

    for( var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++ ){
        for( var unit in units ){
            if( parts[i].indexOf(unit) != -1 ){
               // replace the expression by calculated part.
               expression = expression.replace(parts[i],units[unit](parts[i]));
               break;
            }
        }
    }
    // And now compute it. though eval is evil but in some cases its a good friend.
    // Though i wish there was math. calc
    element.css(property,eval(expression));
}
```

Comment: It needs a usage example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use calc in your CSS file use a polyfill like [PolyCalc](https://github.com/Eccenux/PolyCalc). Should be light enough to work on mobile browsers (e.g. below iOS 6 and below Android 4.4 phones).