# Is there a CSS-only fallback for calc() for IE8

Tags: css

I know there is a [CSS fallback for `calc()` for IE6-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034397/css-calc-alternative). Likewise, I know there is [a jQuery alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117216/css-width-calc100-100px-alternative-using-jquery).

However, **is there a CSS-only fallback for `calc()` for IE8?** If so, what is it?

Comment: No. there is not. You could anyway work it out using js expressions.

Comment: The only CSS fallback is to set a fixed width/height before the calc()

Comment: You would need to modify HTML, adding one extra (neutral container to increase or decrease  value (positive or negative margin for instance), for other situation i don't think of, i have no idea.

Comment: @GCyrillus, in other words, no, there isn't a CSS-only solution. ;)

Comment: it was already said , wasn'it ? if you drop expression and js  and css , it might still be a turn around for IE8, that was my point :)

Comment: You could use a Javascript polyfill like [this one](https://github.com/CJKay/PolyCalc/blob/master/polycalc.js). Yes, that might be a JS solution, but it would allow you to use the standard CSS code. (note: I haven't actually tried that polyfill script yet; just found it on google now)

Comment: @Spudley, thanks for the suggestion. It seemed promising, but it didn't work when I tried it. (Edit: Ah, it requires CSSParser. Shame.)

Comment: @DerekHenderson - that's a pity. As I said, I hadn't tried it, but it looked like it would be useful.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108573/is-there-a-css-only-fallback-for-calc-for-ie8

Comment: @lachore, that's a bit recursive, don't you think, pasting a link in a question back to that very same question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support dynamic properties above IE 8

> Dynamic properties (also called "CSS expressions") are no longer supported in Internet Explorer 8 and later, in IE8 Standards mode and higher.

Source: [Read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Yep, thanks. Already read that link, as it was included in the comments to the first post I referenced in the question. This is why I was asking if there was a fallback that worked in IE8.

Comment: @DerekHenderson, OK, if you dont like it.

Comment: This is a very misleading response. This is about the old expression method, and has nothing to do with calc.

Answer (score 7):

You can do like this

```
.content{
    padding-right: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/FYB4q/

Comment: What does that have to do with the question?

Comment: @OllyHodgson Calc is commonly used to combine percentages with pixel values, which was what I was trying to do. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434602/css-setting-width-height-as-percentage-minus-pixels

Comment: This is a complete copy from the answer of the linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18570513/651170

Comment: @deathlock I can't see much similarity with the answers. I would suggest to report "duplicate" threfore reputed members can review your suggestion 