# How can I select the element which style is defined specific value?

Tags: jquery

In safari browser my background-image is not working. When I inspected in safari I found there the css3 calc() function is not working. I have used like this

```
width: calc(100% - 345px);
height: calc(100% - 180px);
```

Does safari do not support calc() function? If not, how can make a function with jQuery that my calc() function would work.

**Edit**

I've defined calc() function many times in my stylesheet. So I would like to use jQuery but **how do I select the element which value is defined calc()?**

Suppose the following div I have applied with css

```
div.one{width: 300px;}
div.two{width: 300px;}
div.three{width: 200px;}
```

How can select those divs which width is defined 300px?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/calc You have to prefix it with -webkit-calc

Comment: Ah, then it won't work. It was first introduced in version 6.

Comment: so, how can I make it work using jQuery?

Comment: Check this for possible answer [css width: calc(100% -100px); alternative using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117216/css-width-calc100-100px-alternative-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$('selector').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=345px');
$('selector').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=180px');
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it sounds like you're using a browser version that doesn't support the feature you're using.

When deciding whether or not to use a given feature, you should check for browser compatibility at the [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/) site. This will also tell you whether you need to use vendor prefixes, and about any known issues with the feature.

Please note that even when a specific browser feature does work in your browser, you need to consider your end users as well -- use the CanIUse site to check for support across all browsers and versions that you need to support. You should also test your site in a variety of browsers and browser versions.

In the case of `calc()`, you could consider using [this polyfill](https://github.com/CJKay/PolyCalc/blob/master/polycalc.js) to back-port the `calc()` feature into older browsers that don't support it.