# css calc function using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

As browsers like ie doesn't support css calc function. so is there any way to get this working in jquery.

this is how it is done in css

```
.sidebar-one {
height: calc(100% - 135px);
```

The above code decreases 135px from its 100% height. 
Now how can it be in jquery

Comment: This should help: [css width: calc(100% -100px); alternative using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117216/css-width-calc100-100px-alternative-using-jquery)

Comment: Note: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc. IE does support `calc()`, just maybe not in the version(s) you need to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  var sidebar = $('.sidebar-one');
  sidebar.height(sidebar.height() - 135);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L5z7a/