# setting the width on inline-block elements, CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem having two divs side by side of each other. Left div(sidebar) set to a fix width and I want the right div("content") to take up the remaining space on the right. At the moment, I can set the right div to take a fixed width, on the right. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/enphobxb/) I want this done without setting a margin-left on the sidebar.

Thanks

Html

```
<div style="height: 100%">
  <div id="Header"></div>
     <div id="container">
        <div id="sidebar"></div>
        <div id="content">fff</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to your issue? did my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

You just need remove `float:left;` on `#content` so that it takes the remaining space :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/enphobxb/3/)**

EDIT :

If you want a transparent background on the sidebar, you need to add `left-margin:240px` to `#content` so that the content doesn't appear through the sidebar (demo updated)

Comment: hi thanks for the demo. but if you set the    opacity:0.3; to the side bar.. then actually the content div is taking up the side bar. so content div color is having an effect on the sidebar color when it shouldn't.

Comment: @user3105158 ok, you need to add a left-margin to the content then : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/enphobxb/3/

Answer (score 0):

## Want to use inline-block?

In the title you specify `display: inline-block`.

We can do this and keep the sidebar fixed using [`calc(100% - 240px)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) to remove the sidebar width from the width of `#content`.

- Having the divs like this: `<div id="sidebar"></div><div id="content">fff</div>` prevents an inline gap. [More information here](http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).
- I have removed the scroll with `height: calc(100% - 30px)` on `#container` to remove the header height. Not critical enough for an old browser fallback.

**Browser support**: Of course, be aware of [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) using `calc()` - IE 9 +. We can use an un-optimised fallback width for older browsers or, if *really needed*, I have included a basic jQuery `calc()` fallback that will set the width if `calc()` is not supported.

The jQuery fallback is [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11117293/2930477). I added a width check so it will only run when the width is too small. This is particularly good if you include the jQuery library anyway.

### Example

Note `vertical-align: top` to keep the inline-block divs positioned correctly vertically.

```js
// calc fallback - optional

var checkWidth = $('#outer').width() - 240;
var contentWidth = $('#content').width();

if (checkWidth !== contentWidth) {
  alert('no calc :(');
  $('#content').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=240px');
  $(window).resize(function() {
    $('#content').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=240px');
  });
} else {
  alert('has calc :D !');  
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#Header {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
#container {
  height: calc(100% - 30px);
  width: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: 240px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#content {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 240px);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height: 100%" id="outer">
  <div id="Header"></div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div><div id="content">fff</div>
  </div>
</div>
```