# jquery css doesn't work well in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to do fallback for `calc()` in my css with jquery

**CSS:**

```
width: calc(100% - 90px);
```

so I wrote below code but seem the 2nd `css()` doesn't run. I think something is wrong but I've no clue.

**jQuery:**

```
var paxWidth = '-' + ($('.pax').width() + 10) + 'px';
console.log(paxWidth); // this return -90px
$('.datetime,.placeholder').css('width','100%').css('width', paxWidth);
```

Comment: What is the point to set `width` twice? `paxWidth` simply rewrites `'100%'` value.

Comment: You mentioned that paxWidth returns -90px. Width cannot be negative. This might be the reason

Comment: Looks like `pacWidth` contains something like `-90px`. You can not set negative `width` to an HTML element.

Comment: @Regent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117216/css-width-calc100-100px-alternative-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set width with `css` method twice in a row the second simply overwrites previous. In your case to mimic `100% - 90px` width you need to actually calculate this difference in `px` and apply the result.

Now, percentage width `100%` is calculated relatively to a parent container, it means that for 100% value you need to do something like this:

```
var paxWidth = $('.pax').width() + 10;
$('.datetime, .placeholder').css('width', function() {
    var parentWidth = $(this).parent().width();
    return parentWidth - paxWidth;
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/02cxqpzq/

**UPD**. Looking at duplicated answer, I can confirm that my above solution makes little sense since it can be as simple as

```
$('.datetime, .placeholder').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=90px');
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/02cxqpzq/1/

Comment: why does this guy answer got many upvotes : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117216/css-width-calc100-100px-alternative-using-jquery ??

Comment: Interesting, didn't know about it! I think this is a right way to do it. Did you try it?