# How to do calculations with variables in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating a program to allow a user to change most CSS properties of a div. I need it to be centred though, the way I usually do this is with the CSS code below.

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  right: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

I need to make the width and height their own variables however and then do a calculation for the top and right properties which will divide them by 2 and take away from 50%.

```
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
var top = (height / 2);
var right = (width / 2);

$('div')
  .css('position','fixed')
  .css('background','black')
  .css('width',width + 'px')
  .css('height',height + 'px')
  .css('top','calc(50% - ' + top + 'px)')
  .css('right','calc(50% - ' + right + 'px)');
```

How can I go about achieving a centred div while using variables as the values for CSS properties?

Comment: You might see [CSS calc alternative using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11117216/css-width-calc100-100px-alternative-using-jquery)

Comment: It does not give me the same result as the pure CSS above. I am trying to centre something in the screen.

Comment: I suggest to do the calculations and then apply the results to keep your code clear and maintainable... to get the 50% of the width you can try to use the width of your window or parent element if centered...

Comment: use margin:0 auto

Comment: I am half way there, I just need to change the "50px" in top and right properties to the variable names top and right instead. Look here http://codepen.io/Alanay/pen/zNdGJp

Comment: It seems I cannot use variables called "top" or "right"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to support crappy IE CSS variables are an option.

**CSS**

1. Pick a scope in your stylesheet. The higher the selector is on the DOM, the more it'll cover. In the Snippet I chose the highest possible: `:root` (i.e. `html`).
2. Declare CSS variable: `:root --half: 50px` CSSVar must be prefixed with 2 dashes. In the Snippet I have declared a `--half` on `:root` with the value of `50px`.
3. Next, assign CSSVar to the appropriate properties:

   - `top: calc(50% - var(--half));`
   - `right: calc(50% - var(--half));`

**JavaScript**

1. Details are commented in Snippet.

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Reference the input
var A = document.getElementById('input1');

// On input event on input#A call setHalf() function
A.addEventListener('input', setHalf, false);

/* setHalf() accesses the CSS by the CSSDeclaration 
|| interface.
*/
function setHalf(e) {
  // Reference the div
  var X = document.getElementById('shape1');

  /* Get div#shape1 computedStyle in order to 
  || access it's ruleset declarations.
  */
  var Y = window.getComputedStyle(X);

  // Get the value of the CSSVar --half
  var Z = Y.getPropertyValue('--half');

  // Set --half value to the value of input#A
  X.style.setProperty('--half', this.value + 'px');
}
```

```css
:root {
  --half: 50px;
}
#shape1 {
  position: fixed;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: calc(50% - var(--half));
  right: calc(50% - var(--half));
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='shape1'></div>
<input id='input1' type='number' min='-150' max='150' value='50'>
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I am unable to use the words "top" or "right" as variable names.

Here is the code that ended up working.

```
var width = 100;
var height = 100;
var test1 = width / 2;
var test2 = height / 2;

$('div')
  .css('position','fixed')
  .css('background','black')
  .css('width',width + 'px')
  .css('height',height + 'px')
  .css({'top':'calc(50% - ' + test1 + 'px)'})
  .css({'right':'calc(50% - ' + test2 + 'px)'});
```

Comment: That's really weird. Do you have them defined in a parent scope that could be causing issues?

Comment: Nope, it's either just jQuery or the host I'm using (Codepen).