# Calc() on a numbered CSS class?

Tags: html, css, calc

Say I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="bigSquare">
   <div class="square0 square"></div>
   <div class="square1 square"></div>
   <div class="square2 square"></div>
   <div class="square3 square"></div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.bigSquare {
   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
}

.square {
   position: absolute;
   height: 40px;
   width: 40px;
}

.square0 {
   left: 5px;
   top: 5px
}

.square1 {
   left: 55px;
   top: 5px
}

.square2 {
   left: 5px;
   top: 55px
}

.square3 {
   left: 55px;
   top: 55px
}
```

Is it possible to reduce the square0, square1, square2, and square3 CSS down to something that looks like this?

```
.square[n] {
   left: calc((n % 2) * 50px + 5px);
   top: calc((n / 2) * 50px + 5px);
}
```

I realize that the % operator isn't legal but maybe there's an equivalent.

Comment: If you use a CSS preprocessor like Sass, probably.

Comment: Take a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41838310/2813224). I made a demo using CSS Variables that looks very similar to what you are trying to do. Upvote it if it helps. BTW `%` is an remainder operator  (i.e. the remainder of a quotient)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the syntax you expected, but you can use attr:

```
<div class="square" rel="1"></div>
<div class="square" rel="2"></div>
```

```
.square{
   left:calc( attr(rel) / 2 * 50px + 5px);
   top: calc( attr(rel) mod 2 * 50px + 5px);
}
```

This may do the trick.